# fetching primary keys from multiple records-laravel

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I need to pull array of primary keys in single shot

i.e

```
select p_k from table where 1=1
```

result should be

```
$p_k=array(1,2,5,7)
```

i tried

```
$news = DB::table('news')
```

**but for id i need to make a loop. isn't there a shortcut method via orm**

my table is

```
id                   heading                 news
1                    heading1                news1
2                    heading2                news2
```

I need list of id(primary key) in array
like below

```
array(1,2)
```

`$news = DB::table('news')` will fecth all fields and furthermore i need to go through the loop

```
foreach($news as $val){
 $id[]=$val->id
}
```

This is quite lenghty.. i need a shortcut method so that i can directly pull those primary key on array with out loop

i need  do to so because i have another bridge table where these news_id are linked

```
NewsTag::destroy($newsidarray);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to explain properly

Comment: Do you have a `News` model for `news` table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$news = News::lists('id');
```

Using your `News` model (`Eloquent`) with the combination of `lists` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ids = DB::table('news')->lists('id');
```

This will do it. Reference is here-

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Comment: thank you .. this worked too.. sometime we may not need model.. someone must think before downvoting

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Why not look at the docs link I have given?

Comment: $news = DB::table('category_news')
      ->whereIn('category_id', $data['categories'])->lists('id'); worked like a charm

Comment: Oops! my fault, you didn't call `get`.

Comment: @timus2001 Indeed. But people usually don't. Anyways, Glad that it worked.

Comment: Sorry! it was my fault but `+1` i didn't see that you didn't call `get` :-)

Comment: :)... similary someone downvoted my question also hehe

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha No issues. We helped :)